# Remove duplicates within a table in the case of a 2D matrix

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have found a lot of threads on removing duplicates in arrays but none for my specific use-case. I have a 2D matrix and I would like to remove duplicate occurrences within the same table.

I have this:

```
[['<>', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', '*'], [], [], []]
```

which I would like to transform into this:

`[['<>', 'a', 'b', '*'], [], [], []]`

Appreciate any help

Comment: And you did _what_ to get to where you want to be? [mre]? What is your problem with your code?

Comment: Do you also want to deduplicate across rows? (eg `[[1, 2],[2, 3]]` -> `[[1], [2, 3]]` or  `[[1, 2], [3]]`) Note that the use of the term 'matrix' may be misleading as that suggests constant numbers of rows and columns (you may use a sparse representation though, but you should say so if that is true),

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do this,

```
arr = [['<>', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', '*'], [], [], []]

unique = list(map(set, arr))
unique = list(map(list, unique))
print(unique)
```

Output -

```
[['b', '*', 'a', '<>'], [], [], []]
```

The first line just converts the lists inside the variable `arr` into Python `sets`. Sets never allow duplicates in them so they are the best way to get all the unique values from any type of series.

Once I have a list of sets, I convert these sets back into lists using the second line.

Comment: That solution does not preserve order and fails in deduplicating across rows (unsure whether the OP wants the latter).

Comment: @collapsar How does this fail in deduplicating across rows? The output doesn't have any duplicate values. Please elaborate

Comment: it does not work for `[['<>', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', '*'], ['c', 'a', 'd'], [], []]`. Unlikely that the OP only wanted substitutions within a single row or the specific 'matrix' he provides. After all he mentions that he already knows about dedup in arrays.

Comment: @collapsar I don't get it. I tried the code for the example you gave and it was able to deduplicate it. I agree that the output is not in the exact same order as OP's desired output, but for the deduplicating part the code does the job.

Comment: Your code maps `[['<>', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', '*'], ['c', 'a', 'd'], [], []]` to `[['*', '<>', 'b', 'a'], ['d', 'a', 'c'], [], []]`. As you can see, the result has `a` in 2 rows while it shouldn't, if deduplication is supposed to work across row boundaries (granted, it is unclear whether the OP wants that, but likely he does).

Comment: Ok, as he accepted your answer, I stand corrected ...

Comment: yes it's good for me @IshanShishodiya, thx for the help !